# how to join dataframes without losing their names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to join dataframes without losing their names

I have several dataframes in a list and by joining them I am losing the identification of each one because they have equal columns.

```
ticker_list = ['SBSP3.SA', 'CSMG3.SA', 'CGAS5.SA']
pd_list = [pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(ticker)) for ticker in ticker_list]


for index, df in enumerate(pd_list):
    df['source'] = ticker_list[index]

df = pd.concat(pd_list,axis = 1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny9TF.png)

I'm getting the following output:

as the dataframes have columns equal I just don't know which entry belongs to which csv file

how do i put the identification of each one in the dungeons? example:

```
          Date    High_SBSP3.SA   Low_SBSP3.SA   Open_SBSP3.SA  Close_SBSP3.SA      Volume_SBSP3.SA   Adj Close_SBSP3.SA
0   2017-01-02            14.70          14.60           14.64           14.66            7525700.0          13.880955
1   2017-01-03            15.65          14.95           14.95           15.50           39947800.0          14.676315
2   2017-01-04            15.68          15.31           15.45           15.50           37071700.0          14.676315
3   2017-01-05            15.91          15.62           15.70           15.75           47586300.0          14.913031
4   2017-01-06            15.92          15.50           15.78           15.66           25592000.0          14.827814
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, copy and paste a example of your dataframe's and your expected output

Comment: your approach is not recommendable. It is better to `concat` using multiindex columns to easily visualize each sub-dataframe within the concatenated dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `add_sufix` when reading.

```
pd_list = [pd.read_csv(f'{ticker}.csv').add_suffix(ticker) for ticker in ticker_list]
```

---

OR you can `concat` through `axis=0` and define the ticker as another columns

```
pd_list = [pd.read_csv(f'{ticker}.csv').assign(ticker=ticker) for ticker in ticker_list]

df = pd.concat(pd_list)
```